# mask div with overlay, prevent scroll of mask

Tags: css, html

I have a div with scrollable content. I want to add a color mask to it that overlays the content, but will not scroll with the content.   http://jsfiddle.net/6e9t1wt3/1/

```
  *{box-sizing:border-box;}
  #main{position:relative; border: 1px solid blue; height: 400px; overflow: auto;}
  #main:before {
      content:'';
      width:100%;
      height:100%;background:red;position:fixed;
  }

<div id="stuff">


  <div id="main">
      <div class="loading-mask">Loading...</div>
      <table class="data">
          <tr><td>stuff</td></tr>
          <tr><td>stuff</td></tr>
          <tr><td>stuff</td></tr>
          <tr><td>stuff</td></tr>
          <tr><td>stuff</td></tr>
          <tr><td>stuff</td></tr>
          <tr><td>stuff</td></tr>
          <tr><td>stuff</td></tr>
          <tr><td>stuff</td></tr>
          <tr><td>stuff</td></tr>
          <tr><td>stuff</td></tr>
          <tr><td>stuff</td></tr>
          <tr><td>stuff</td></tr>
          <tr><td>stuff</td></tr>
          <tr><td>stuff</td></tr>
          <tr><td>stuff</td></tr>
          <tr><td>stuff</td></tr>
          <tr><td>stuff</td></tr>
          <tr><td>stuff</td></tr>
          <tr><td>stuff</td></tr>
          <tr><td>stuff</td></tr>
          <tr><td>stuff</td></tr>
          <tr><td>stuff</td></tr>
          <tr><td>stuff</td></tr>
          <tr><td>stuff</td></tr>
          <tr><td>stuff</td></tr>
          <tr><td>stuff</td></tr>
          <tr><td>stuff</td></tr> 
      </table>
  </div>
```

In my fiddle you will see the mask but when I scroll down in my div it scrolls away. do i need to use position fixed or absolute? thanks for advice!

Comment: Circumventing the "code must be included in the question" filter is inappropriate, it is there for a reason.  Also, this has nothing to do with Sass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap content of that scrollable area in a wrapper, and `position` it also `absolutely`. Make that wrapper scrollable with `overflow:auto`. Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ilpo/6e9t1wt3/2/

HTML:

```
<div id="main">
    <div class="loading-mask">Loading...</div>
    <div class="content">
        <!-- content here -->
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#main {
    position:relative;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    height: 400px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.loading-mask {
    padding: 10px;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    background: rgba(3, 3, 3, 0.8);
    width:100%;
}
.content {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    overflow:auto;
}
```